# Can I insert the dummy data or disable cache line to Rocket core cache?

Tags: caching, riscv, rocket-chip

I'm now following up a Cache compression using Rocket Core in Chipyard. Since compression is quite complex, so I want to multiply the ways, and copy the inserted data in Cache for the comparision with original Riscv.

For example, if the cache block is compressed by 4 times(memory A) and 2 times(memory B), instead of inserting 1/4 size(memory A) and 1/2 size memory(memory B), I'll increase way 4 times and insert A single time, and insert B memory 2 times.

Since cache can't save same data in different cache memory, so I want to insert dummy data for B or disable single line as B is saved in chosen area. Is it possible..?

Could you guys help..?